# How do I determine of the user guesses wrong in the game of hangman c#

Tags: c#, console

I am working on the game of hangman and I am trying to figure out how to display a message and increase a number by 1 if the user guesses a letter that is not in the word. Right now what is happening is when the user guesses a letter that is not in the word is displays a message for every letter that is in the word and increases a number by one for every letter that is in the word.

I am trying to make it so that when the user makes a wrong guess it only displays that message once and only increases the number by one. Here is the code that I have that determines when the user guesses wrong

```
for (int index = 0; index < charArray.Length; index++)
            {
                if (charArray[index] == userGuess && userGuess != lettersUsed[index])
                {
                    found[index] = userGuess;
                    lettersUsed[index] = userGuess;
                }
                else if (lettersUsed[index] == userGuess)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{userGuess} is already in the word");
                }
                else if (charArray[index] != userGuess)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{userGuess} is not in the word");
                    guesses++;
                }
            }
```

Any suggestions would be awesome!

Comment: What's the difference between lettersUsed and found? They seem to store the same data.

Comment: Good point! its kinda pointless. I should does use found but I would I determine if they guess a letter that is not in the word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the letter is already in the word. You print the "x is already in the word" message charArray.Length() amount of times. Use a bool to determine if the letter was found and then print the message only once afterwards.

```
class HangmanGame
{
    char[] charArray = {'h', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'm', 'a', 'n'};
    char[] found = {'*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'};
    int guesses = 0;

    public void TestLetter(char userGuess)
    {
        bool foundLetter = false, alreadyInWord = false;
        for (int index = 0; index < charArray.Length; index++)
        {
            if(userGuess == found[index])
            {
                alreadyInWord = true;
                break;
            }
            else if(userGuess == charArray[index])
            {
                found[index] = charArray[index];
                foundLetter = true;
            }
        }
        if(alreadyInWord)
        {
            String s = "The letter " + userGuess + " was already in the word: " + new string(found) + ".";
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        else if(foundLetter)
        {
            String s = "You guessed correctly: " + new string(found) + ".";
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        else
        {
            guesses++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I reckon the charArray is meant to store the original word, that the user is trying to guess. If I were you I'd look at List for storing the characters the user found.

```cs
var found = new List<char>();

...

if (charArray.Any(c => c == userGuess)) // If any character in the char array equals to the guess
{
    if (found.Any(c => c == userGuess))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{userGuess} is already in the word");
    }
    else
    {
        found.Add(userGuess);
    }
}
else 
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{userGuess} is not in the word");
    guesses++;
}
```

Any by the way is a Linq extension method, which checks if any element of a collection matches the predicate you enter as a parameter. For that you have to use a javascript-like arrow function syntax.